# Setting max height affects z-index

Tags: html, css

So I want the "content" div to appear over the "cover" div, which works fine normally, but once I set the max-height for the "content" div, it fails to do so.

[Minimum reproducible here](https://jsfiddle.net/e16y4anc/2/). You can see if you remove line 66 of the CSS it would behave as expected, but acts up with line 66 somehow.

Help appreciated! Thank you.

Attached is the code if anyone wonders:
HTML:

```
<div class = "wrapper">
            <div class="card-container">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="cover"></div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">
                            <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
                            <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
                            <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
                            <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
                            <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
                            <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
                            <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
                            <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
                            <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
                            <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
                            <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.card-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #d9b3ff;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cover:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-left: 150px solid transparent;
    border-right: 150px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid #cc99ff;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 20;
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transition: all 1s 1s ease;
}

.content {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.content p {
    position: relative;
}

.card:hover .cover:before {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.card:hover .content {
    top: -80px;
    transition: all 1s 1s ease;
}

/*Actual text stuff*/
.text {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 5px;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 200px; /* This line causes the problem */
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.text::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE and Edge */
.text {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

Comment: You're simply limiting the height of the text, in this case there should be a scrollbar to give access to the rest of the content but you've hidden that as well. you can try scrolling using the mouse wheel.

Comment: I'm not too sure about what you mean - even with the max height, I can still scroll over the div to view the rest of the content. You can see my fiddle for that, or did you mean hiding the scroll bar will affect the z-index?

Comment: Exactly, All you did is that you lowered it's maximum height which gave you the ability to scroll within it instead if the body. `z-index` has nothing to do with anything which should be clear enough because there's no `z-index` applied to `.text`

Comment: Thanks for the insight - however, even after removing the CSS portion of hiding the scroll bar, with max height still present the display is still messed up. Could it be for other reasons?[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e16y4anc/3/)

Comment: The layout being messed is up to you and the styles you've previously had, Side note the ability to hide the scrollbar is only available for chrome as of now

Comment: Are you going for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/f8ckh7a9/

Comment: Wait this actually looks pretty good! Thank you so much, I will try to apply it to my actual code

Comment: Great @MaggieMao, I've added it as an answer along with an explanation of the thought process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be going for something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/f8ckh7a9/).

In short and as mentioned in the comments, the issue is not the height affecting the `z-index`. `z-index` is not affected by the dimensions of an element. Instead the main issue is the switched layering of children elements that needs to happen on hover of the parent elements.

To accomplish this, you need to ensure that all layers (as indicated by elements with differing `z-index` are siblings. This allows you to swap their order visually.

Main changes necessary to do this:

1. Move .cover, .card and .content so they are all direct children of .card-container and siblings of each other.
2. Ensure the z-index for .content, .card and .cover are in ascending order when .card-container is not hovered and then descending order when hovered.
3. Limit your `transitions` to specific properties rather than "all" to more accurately control transforms.

Answer (score 0):

change `max-width:250px;` and `max-height:175px` to make the content fit in the "text" div.

after that add a scroll bar to give the user an cue to scroll down.

Comment: So there's no way I can only show part of the text AND have the content show up above cover?

Comment: you can set the opacity of the text div to 0 and then add an hover effect to change the opacity back to 1.